# How to iterate over a range of keys in a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

How do you iterate over a range of keys in a dictionary?

for example, if I have the following dictionary:

```
{'Domain Source': 'Analyst', 'Recommend Suppress': 'N', 'Standard Error': '0.25', 'Element ID': '1.A.1.d.1', 'N': '8', 'Scale ID': 'IM', 'Not Relevant': 'n/a', 'Element Name': 'Memorization', 'Lower CI Bound': '2.26', 'Date': '06/2006', 'Data Value': '2.75', 'Upper CI Bound': '3.24', 'O*NET-SOC Code': '11-1011.00'}
```

how would I iterate over only the keys after standard error? Ideally, I would like to get all the values following standard error.

Thanks!

---

Just to address the comment: I know about iteritems(), but when I tried subscripting, returned an error: not subscriptable. Also, the key / values come in the same order every time.

Comment: You can iterate over the keys using the iterkeys() method. ex: [key for key in mydict.iterkeys()].

Comment: @HugoCorrá That is only usefull in the keys in a dict are stored in the order that they were inserted, therefore see the answer of jterrace

Comment: Sorry, I had misunderstood. Now I understand the importance of the ordered v. unordered dictionaries.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The keys in a Python dictionary are not in any specific order.

You'll want to use an [OrderedDict](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) instead.

For example:

```
>>> d = OrderedDict([('key1', 'value1'), ('key2', 'value2'), ('key3', 'value3')])
```

Now the keys are guaranteed to be returned in order:

```
>>> d.keys()
['key1', 'key2', 'key3']
```

If you want to grab all keys after a specific value, you can use [itertools.dropwhile](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.dropwhile):

```
>>> import itertools
>>> list(itertools.dropwhile(lambda k: k != 'key2', d.iterkeys()))
['key2', 'key3']
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that Python dictionaries are unordered, so it doesn't really make sense to iterate over keys after `'Standard Error'`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, dictionaries are unordered. Once you've made it, there's no way you could rely on order of items. So if you want general solution, you could use [OrderedDict](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)

If you already have your data in the dictionary, you can exclude two first keys explicitly:

```
>>> d = {'Domain Source': 'Analyst', 'Recommend Suppress': 'N', 'Standard Error': '0.25', 'Element ID': '1.A.1.d.1', 'N': '8', 'Scale ID': 'IM', 'Not Relevant': 'n/a', 'Element Name': 'Memorization', 'Lower CI Bound': '2.26', 'Date': '06/2006', 'Data Value': '2.75', 'Upper CI Bound': '3.24', 'O*NET-SOC Code': '11-1011.00'}
>>> [x for x in d if x not in ('Domain Source', 'Recommend Suppress')]
['N', 'Scale ID', 'Not Relevant', 'Element Name', 'Data Value', 'Standard Error', 'Element ID', 'Lower CI Bound', 'Date', 'Upper CI Bound', 'O*NET-SOC Code']
```

Answer (score 2):

A dictionary doesn't store the key/value pairs in the same order that you added them ... unless an [`OrderedDict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) is used. Here's how:

```
entries = [('Domain Source', 'Analyst'), ('Recommend Suppress', 'N'),
 ('Standard Error', '0.25'), ('Element ID', '1.A.1.d.1'),
 ('N', '8'), ('Scale ID', 'IM'), ('Not Relevant', 'n/a'),
 ('Element Name', 'Memorization'), ('Lower CI Bound', '2.26'),
 ('Date', '06/2006'), ('Data Value', '2.75'), 
 ('Upper CI Bound', '3.24'), ('O*NET-SOC Code', '11-1011.00')]

from collections import OrderedDict
d = OrderedDict(entries)
d.keys()[2:]

=> ['Standard Error', 'Element ID', 'N', 'Scale ID', 'Not Relevant',
    'Element Name', 'Lower CI Bound', 'Date', 'Data Value',
    'Upper CI Bound', 'O*NET-SOC Code']
```